# Android Studio / Robolectric tests fails randomly

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle, android-testing, robolectric

I am using Android Studio 3.3 and I have some tests with Robolectric 3.3.2.

I have multiple problems that may be connected.

- I start Android studio and run my test class. It is OK. If I modify / add a test, it is not seen when I rerun the tests (right click on the class then run tests). I tried to invalidate cache and restart, build / rebuild project. It does not work. I have to restart Android Studio.
- Furthermore, it happens that I get an error: Initialization failed / Empty test suite.

I do not have a clue where it comes from.

- I also have a third problem:

```
    No such manifest file: build/intermediates/bundles/debug/AndroidManifest.xml

    java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 13
    Exception Details:
      Location:
        com/package/name/class.method(Ljava/util/List;Ljava/lang/String;I)Ljava/lang/String; @0: aload_0
      Reason:
        Expected stackmap frame at this location.
      Bytecode:
        0x0000000: 2a2b 1cb8 0038 2a2b 1cb8 0024 b04e 2dbf
        0x0000010: 4ebb 000d 5911 ea84 2db7 002b bf       
      Exception Handler Table:
        bci [0, 12] => handler: 13
        bci [0, 12] => handler: 16
```

I also tried to have my dependencies and project in Java 6...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior was really weird. It happens on all people working on the project. The solution (for now) was to delete all test files.

Then copy them back.

Hope it can help other people.